# Zooming with D3 JS bar charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, zooming, bar-chart

I have made a bar chart which displays dates along the bottom (these can be daily, weekly etc) and it also has a line graph over the top of it too to show extra comparison values. Now I'm trying to add zoom functionality to the graph using the different examples from the D3 JS website but I'm not having much joy.

These are my variables so far:

```
function pullIdArray(data) {
        var s = {};
        data.forEach(function(d) { s[d.date] = true; });
        var ret = [];
        for (var k in s) {
            console.log(k);
            ret.push(d3.time.format(dateFormatPattern)(new Date(k)))
        }
        console.log(ret);
        return ret;
    }    

    var margin = {top: 60, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 60},
        width = $('.svg-container').width() - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(pullIdArray(data))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .2);

    var y = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([height, 0]);

    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .tickFormat(function(d) {
            return d3.time.format(dateFormatPattern)(new Date(d));
        });

    var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(5)
        .tickFormat(function(d) { return d + " kWh" });

    var zoom = d3.behavior.zoom()
        .x(x)
        .y(y)
        .scaleExtent([1, 10])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    function zoomed() {
        svg.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
        svg.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    }

    function reset() {
        d3.transition().duration(750).tween("zoom", function() {
            var ix = d3.interpolate(x.domain(), [-width / 2, width / 2]),
                iy = d3.interpolate(y.domain(), [-height / 2, height / 2]);
            return function(t) {
                zoom.x(x.domain(ix(t))).y(y.domain(iy(t)));
                zoomed();
            };
        });
    }

    var svg = d3.select(".svg-container svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    svg.call(tip);
    svg.call(zoom);
```

The zoom function doesn't seem to like that I'm using rangeRoundBands to show my bar chart and when I try to scroll the mousewheel over the chart, I get lots of 'undefined is not a function' messages.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Updated code to add in new function pullIdArray.

console.log(ret); shows the following:

```
[ "Aug 22", "Aug 23", "Aug 24", "Aug 25", "Aug 26",
  "Aug 27", "Aug 28", "Aug 29", "Aug 30", "Aug 31",
  "Sep 01", "Sep 02", "Sep 03", "Sep 04", "Sep 05",
  "Sep 06", "Sep 07", "Sep 08", "Sep 09", "Sep 10",
  "Sep 11", "Sep 12", "Sep 13", "Sep 14", "Sep 15",
  "Sep 16", "Sep 17", "Sep 18", "Sep 19", "Sep 20",
  "Sep 21", "Sep 22", "Sep 23", "Sep 24", "Sep 25",
  "Sep 26", "Sep 27", "Sep 28", "Sep 29", "Sep 30",
  "Oct 01", "Oct 02", "Oct 03", "Oct 04", "Oct 05",
  "Oct 06", "Oct 07", "Oct 08", "Oct 09", "Oct 10",
  "Oct 11", "Oct 12", "Oct 13", "Oct 14", "Oct 15",
  "Oct 16", "Oct 17", "Oct 18", "Oct 19", "Oct 20",
  "Oct 21", "Oct 22", "Oct 23", "Oct 24", "Oct 25",
  "Oct 26", "Oct 27", "Oct 28", "Oct 29", "Oct 30",
  "Oct 31", "Nov 01", "Nov 02", "Nov 03", "Nov 04",
  "Nov 05", "Nov 06", "Nov 07", "Nov 08", "Nov 09",
  "Nov 10", "Nov 11", "Nov 12", "Nov 13", "Nov 14",
  "Nov 15", "Nov 16", "Nov 17", "Nov 18", "Nov 19",
  "Nov 20", "Nov 21", "Nov 22", "Nov 23", "Nov 24",
  "Nov 25", "Nov 26", "Nov 27", "Nov 28", "Nov 29"    ]
```

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10159592/is-it-possible-to-use-rangeband-on-an-ordinal-scale-with-a-dynamic-domain) and/or [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13342149/pan-zoom-ordinal-scale) may help.

Comment: I've tried using those questions to sort out my question but I'm a bit confused as to how everything really works so I'm not sure if I'm doing it right. I've edited my answer above to show how my code is at the minute, but I still get undefined function messages when trying to scroll

Comment: You probably want to use a time scale instead of an ordinal scale.

Comment: If I change it to d3.time.scale I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Object function scale(x) {
      return linear(x);
    } has no method 'rangeRoundBands' `

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11126207/zooming-bar-graph-with-d3-js) should help with that.

Comment: I'm having trouble figuring it out, unfortunately I only understand the very basics of the library at the moment. Would you mind editing my code and showing me where I'm going wrong please? It'd be great to learn how

Comment: If I understand correctly, [this](http://www.techsfo.com/blog/2013/08/focus-context-bar-chart-in-javascript/) is more or less what you're looking for.

Comment: Ideally I want to be able to zoom in/out using the mousewheel, something like this but with a bar chart [http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/area-gradient.html]

Comment: Well the example above shows you how to "zoom" into the data for the top bar chart. You can use this to customise how it's done.